# Why can't a thermosetting plastic be stretched like an elastomer?

Tags: polymers

So far I've learnt that there are 2 'types' of thermosets: thermosetting plastics and thermosetting elastomers. Both of them consists of crosslinks that when stretched, allows for the material to spring back into its original shape. So why can't a thermosetting plastic be stretched like an elastomer? Is it something to do  with the degree of crystallinity and elastomers being amorphous?

Sorry if my question is a bit messy, I'm quite new to this topic.

Comment: Only has to do with the chain lenghts between crosslink points. There are thermoplastic elastomers (TPEs) with crystalline crosslinks instead of covalently bonded ones, and they can be relatively rigid or highly elastic. It's all about the geometric molecular structure, not so much what exactly the chemical structure of the crosslink is.